# how to use shell script if else condition block in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

how to use shell script if else condition block in Jenkins declarative pipeline

below are the shell script commands I wanted to run  in a Jenkins pipeline stage,  the way we run them using shell script/command line

```
#!/bin/sh
var=$(git status -s)
echo ${#var}
if [ ${#var} -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "tree is clean"
else
  echo "tree is dirty, please commit changes before running this"
  git add -A
  git commit -m "updated terraform files"
  git push
fi

echo "End of script"
```

These steps are working fine inside Linux and Jenkins shell/command prompt. How do I replicate same inside jenkins pipeline?

This is what I have tried but it's failing

```
# jenkins pipeline

pipeline {
    agent  any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'pwd'
                sh 'sleep 15'
                script {
                    sh 'pwd'
                    sh 'var=$(git status -s)'
                    sh 'echo ${#var}' # till here it's working, but if block it's failing. I guess perhaps because if block is actually written in groovy syntax not linux/shell script 'if else' block
                     if ( ${#var} -eq 0 ) {
                         sh 'echo tree is clean'
                     }else {
                         sh 'echo tree is dirty please commit your code changes'
                     }
                }
                sh 'sleep 5'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quick response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is not quick response but maybe it will be useful for people in the future.

First of all you need to separate `Jenkins` variables and `shell` variables.
What you defined is `shell` variable and you wanted to use it as `Jenkins` variable in `if` statement.

Correct way of applying this will be something like this:

```
# jenkins pipeline

pipeline {
    agent  any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
// This is definition of Jenkins variables
// Please be aware that you can refer to it only in current stage
                def nodeVersion = sh(script: "node --version", returnStdout: true).trim()
                def currentPath = sh(script: "pwd", returnStdout: true).trim()
                def gitStatus = sh(script: "git status -s", returnStdout: true).trim()

// This will make output of `gitStatus` global variable that you can use in any stage
                env.GIT_STATUS = gitStatus

// Now you can use this variable in Jenkins if statement
                if ( gitStatus == 0 ) {
                      sh 'echo tree is clean'
                } else {
                     sh 'echo tree is dirty please commit your code changes'
                }
                sh 'sleep 5'
            }
        }
    }
}
```